# How I can receice each new record in /var/log/syslog to my Net Core daemon

Tags: linux, .net-core

I want to monitoring and receive each new record in my NET CORE 6 application. I have created various system daemon for Linux with Net Core permanently, each month, this is most convenient task for me with Net Core.

But I don't understand how I cat receive to my daemon each new record in /var/log/syslog without periodically repeating

```
tail -n 100 /var/log/syslog
```

and checking new/old records. I searching a way how to receive each new record to my Net Core daemon automatically, without repeating CAT or TAIL. Is it possible?

Comment: uff, terrible solution. You want to become syslog? then become syslog, don't try to watch syslog's output. Other than that, if you're actually ok in .net, you should actually know how to open a file in the programming language of your choice.

Comment: So, the first thing we need to talk about is what you want to achieve here, and on what kind of Linux. Because if the linux system you're using is somewhat "normal", you can just ask journalctl to give you the logs you care about, no reading of a log file necessary. If your linux is ancient/strange, you will have a syslog daemon and need to hook/modify that. But this all is very confusing to me, so maybe explain what you're actually trying to build, in the bigger pictuire, here.

Comment: @MarcusMüller what terrible? My customer create VMs in my KVM server. I must to monitor what exactly each customer doing in my KVM server - this is my job. Of course, I know how to read file PERIODICALLY - io.file.read - that's it what need to read. But I search a way TO AWOID millions repeating of reading log and comparing what records I have read so far and whats records is new. I want a way ONE TIME to attach to this file and receive automatically to my daemon each new records.

Comment: @MarcusMüller. In my project I must to use two type of ubuntu - Ubuntu 16.04.7 LTS and Ubuntu 21.10 (GNU/Linux 5.13.0-41-generic x86_64). Without graphics system, of course.

Comment: I never said anything about reading periodically! Are you aware of async IO? I'm sure that also exists for .net-compatible languages.

Comment: (and yeah, Ubuntu 16.04 is ancient, but still supported, my condolences. Ubuntu 21.10 is already end-of-life and you need to update, or you will no longer receive security updates)

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't understand you, sorry. No difference between Sync and Async reading. This is ONE TIME log reading. For example now (18:54
Sunday, September 4, 2022 (GMT+3)), I  know how to read any file ONE TIME, I need monitor EACH NEW record in syslog. How one time reading is related to monitoring each new records (today, tomorrow, tomorrow after tomottow and so on) WITHOUT REPEATING and checking log again and again for new/old records.

Comment: ... you clearly *don't* understand what asynchronous IO is, and that's fine! Asynchronous IO is when you say "read me the next bytes as soon as they are ready, and notify me when that has happend". So, you kick that off, and as soon as some new bytes are available, they are read. So, you get these bytes, and again kick off a "read the next bytes as soon…".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your actual question can be answered with: please investigate asynchronous IO, where you can request data to be read when it's ready. So, you read all that's already in the file, and then let yourself be notified when the next bunch of data is ready, read that, and repeat.

However, reading the log messages from a file where they, in the very end, are written to by the system's logger daemon, is an inappropriate design for a log centralization; instead, you need something that *delivers* the messages to you, as individual messages, not as lines in a file (*files* and the low-level functions with which you read them have absolutely no notion of what a "line" is, so this all becomes very inefficient).

So.

You should gather the messages as they are passed to your system log, not try to read them from the system log after the fact.

Ubuntu 21.10 uses journald, so I strongly suggest reading the section `FORWARDING TO TRADITIONAL SYSLOG DAEMONS` in `man journald.conf`.  You want to implement the second method mentioned there:

> Journal events can be transferred to a different logging daemon in two different ways. With the first method, messages are immediately forwarded to a socket (/run/systemd/journal/syslog), where the traditional syslog daemon can read them. This method is controlled by the ForwardToSyslog= option. With a second method, a syslog daemon behaves like a normal journal client, and reads messages from the journal files, similarly to journalctl(1).
>
> With this, messages do not have to be read immediately, which allows a logging daemon which is only started late in boot to access all messages since the start of the system. In addition, full structured meta-data is available to it. This method of course is available only if the messages are stored in a journal file at all. So it will not work if Storage=none is set. It should be noted that usually the second method is used by syslog daemons, so the Storage= option, and not the ForwardToSyslog= option, is relevant for them.

So, go ahead and implement a journal client. That actually describes your use case,

> My customer create VMs in my KVM server. I must to monitor what exactly each customer doing in my KVM server - this is my job.

Comment: Thant you. If I correct understand you, I need only read socket /run/systemd/journal/syslog (together with system daemon), of course synchronously or Asynchronously it is no matter at all. Yes, this is a way to avoid cycle with CAT/TAIL. I will create test tomorrow and will continue discussing, Main question is - can my service and system syslog daemon reading the same socket without influence one to another.

Comment: Re: sync/async doesn't matter: NO. I said this thrice now. if you want to follow, you'll need to do it asynchronously, or manually busy-poll the file, which is a terrible idea.

Comment: I have created tests and I understand - you are right about sync/async.

Answer (score 0):

As advice of Marcus Müller, asynchronous reading is key to solve this task.  This is screen of my daemon (currently this is simple desktop application on VB, because this is test only and I have no time to demonize this app).

[image: async read daemon socket]

on the front this is my VB app, behind it I start test container and on the right panel I place test output of docker daemon.

Code is simple and look as

```
Dim Ret1 = Vm.Bash("sudo -S <<< ""XXXXXXXXXXXX"" sudo docker events", New Threading.CancellationTokenSource, AddressOf NewLine, AddressOf ErrLine)
        Ret1.Wait()
        ' this command never ended, only with error <<<---

Sub NewLine(sender As Object, e As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
    Console.WriteLine($"{e.Key}:{e.Value}")
End Sub

Sub ErrLine(sender As Object, e As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, String))
    Console.WriteLine($"Error {e.Key}:{e.Value}")
End Sub
```

the same logic for reading socket directly without docker daemon.